# How to call pdf.php file from Cakephp 3 application?

Tags: php, pdf, cakephp-3.0, fpdf

I have a file `pdf.php` which contains code to develop a pdf file using `FPDF`. I have gone through the tutorials and I cannot call this `pdf.php` file from my form action in my template file.

I have also tried to put the code of `pdf.php`in 'generatepdf.ctp'. It is not working. I think it is because of the headers and footers from the `default.ctp` file.

How to do it?

Comment: This is pretty vague. What specific problems are you having?

Comment: @Kenster I learnt fpdf from fpdf tutorials and have created a php file which will output a pdf file. But I just dont know how to integrate it with cakephp 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the next plugin:

**CakePdf plugin**
https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf

With some of the following libraries:

- DomPdf
- Mpdf
- Tcpdf
- WkHtmlToPdf

Comment: I already have developed the `pdf.php` file using `FPDF`. However I now am using it like another project `PDF/pdf.php` and I am calling it in the form `action = '../PDF/pdf.php'`. This is temporary. Still searching for a better way to do it later.

Comment: I am wondering why you have '.php' in your action. Cake does not work like standard PHP as it is an MVC framework. How familiar are you with CakePHP?